# Can I inject test data into an EC2 API call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda

I've implemented a variation of [Save AWS EC2 Cost by Automatically Stopping Idle Instance Using Lambda and CloudWatch](https://medium.com/@Hironsan/save-aws-ec2-cost-by-automatically-stopping-idle-instance-using-lambda-and-cloudwatch-759edd62b27d) but I want to be able to test it. After reading [Introduction To AWS Lambda For Dummies](https://dashbird.io/blog/aws-lambda-overview-for-dummies/) I can do this by selecting "Configure test events" and adding:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-0123456789abcdef"
  }
}
```

with the id of a known EC2 instance. But what I want to be able to do is inject data that gets read by:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
if instance.instance_type.endswith('xlarge'):
    put_cpu_alarm(instance_id)
```

So I don't have to have an EC2 instance running to test. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the code you have shown.

When the code calls `ec2.Instance()`, it is retrieving real data from the Amazon EC2 service.

If you wish to 'fake' such a call, you would need to modify your code to return a specific response. This is known as a code 'stub', that pretends to behave in a particular way.